# jQuery UI draggable second drag does not revert

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

I'm having some issues with jQuery UI draggable objects. I've built a system where you can drag an icon from the left column of the site onto a droppable area. I have the code set to revert the icon immediately upon dropping the icon (it creates a different object in the droppable area).

The first time you drag any given icon to the droppable area it will revert perfectly. However, the second time you drag the icon and drop it reverts to the correct location vertically within the page, but horizontally it stops at the border of the droppable area.

I'll add some code here shortly but wondered if anyone had this same issue.

Thanks!

Comment: Your odds for getting help improve when you share your code.

Comment: Please provide code. Better yet, use jsfiddle.net

Comment: Working on it now. Sorry. I had to take off to get my son to the neurologist.

Answer (score 0):

I actually just figured it out. I added helper: "clone" to the function call and it works perfectly. Thanks guys